# Axios response interceptor times out with put data, but works without put data

Tags: reactjs, django, axios

Why does the response interceptor not fire for 401 when I use data in put (django server shows 401 due to access_token being outdated, but response interceptor fires timeout of 5000ms exceeded), however if I pass nothing (no data arg in put) fires the response interceptor with 401 as expected.

This code does not trigger 401 in the response interceptor

```
  const updateProfile = async ({ _isPrivate, _color_scheme, _avatar }) => {
    var data= {
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      venmo_username: venmo_username,
      about: about,
      private: _isPrivate,
      color_scheme: _color_scheme,
      avatar: _avatar,
      city: city,
      country: country,
      phone_number: phone_number,
    };
    axiosConfig
      .put(`/api/users/${user.id}/`, data)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          setUser(res.data);
          updateUser(res.data);
        } else if (res.status === 202) {
          var msg = res.data.data;
          Alert.alert(msg);
        }
      })
      .catch((res) => {
        Alert.alert("Error during User Profile update. " + res);
      });
  };
```

Eliminating the parameter does call the 401 in response interceptor

```
  const updateProfile = async ({ _isPrivate, _color_scheme, _avatar }) => {
    axiosConfig
      .put(`/api/users/${user.id}/`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          setUser(res.data);
          updateUser(res.data);
        } else if (res.status === 202) {
          var msg = res.data.data;
          Alert.alert(msg);
        }
      })
      .catch((res) => {
        Alert.alert("Error during User Profile update. " + res);
      });
  };
```

My interceptors look like this.

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";

const baseURL = __DEV__
  ? "http://localhost:8000"
  : "https://api.xxxxxxxx.com";

var access_token = null;
const instance = axios.create({
  // configure the required base properties here
  // any dynamic values will be defined in the interceptor below.
  baseURL: baseURL,
  xsrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFTOKEN",
  xsrfCookieName: "csrftoken",
  timeout: 5000,

  headers: {
    Authorization: access_token ? "Bearer " + access_token : null,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    accept: "*/*",
  },
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    const atoken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("access_token");
    access_token = atoken ? "Bearer " + atoken : null;

    if (access_token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `${access_token}`;
    }
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error) => {
    const originalConfig = error.config;

    if (typeof error.response === "undefined") {
      alert("A server/network error occurred.");
      return Promise.reject(error);
    } else if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalConfig._retry) {
      originalConfig._retry = true;
      await refreshAccessToken();
      return instance(originalConfig);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
);
```

```js
async function refreshAccessToken() {
  const refreshToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("refresh_token");

  await axios
    .post(baseURL + "/auth/token/", {
      grant_type: "refresh_token",
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
      client_id: "XXClient ID XXX",
      client_secret:
        "XXXsecretXXX",
    })
    .then(async ({ data }) => {
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync("access_token", data.access_token);
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync("refresh_token", data.refresh_token);
    })
    .catch(async (err) => {
      try {
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("email");
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("password");
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("access_token");
        await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync("refresh_token");
      } catch (e) {}
    });
}
```

I'm expecting that the interceptor fires the 401 with or without providing data arg in the put statement.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what the problem is with the code provided right now. From what I've seen, I'm guessing you're getting stuck in an infinite loop on the `refreshAccessToken()` side.

Comment: @Odri  Thanks for looking at it.  I've added the refreshAccessToken() code.  Also as I mentioned, it works correctly when there is no data sent with the put but times out when data is sent with the put.